# Reading a file with for statment - Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have this code:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%~dp0\files\text\lead_r.txt") do set /p key= < lead_r.txt
ECHO %key%
PAUSE
```

What I want it to do is to open a specific text file, read it and then write what's in it to `%key%`. It works when `lead_r.txt` and the batch file are in the same folder but it fails when I move `lead.txt` to `\files\text`. There are no files with spaces in `\files\text` so i don't know where the problem is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to understand your goal, but try next code snippet:

```
@echo off >Nul 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%~dp0\files\text\lead_r.txt") do (
rem the same file in next line 
rem set /p key=< lead_r.txt
set /p key= < %%a
ECHO !key!
PAUSE
)
endlocal
```

Here mind `EnableDelayedExpansion` keyword of [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) command = Expand variables at execution time rather than at parse time, if used `!key!` syntax instead of `%key%` one.